Issue listing team folders with dropbox javascript sdk
I need a critical help with question below.
i am developing a backup and restore solution which backups data from dropbox and store in s3 bucket. I am using typescript lambda to achieve the same
Now I have been so far successful listing the users in a dropbiox business account and listing their files and folders successfully
Some snippets of code related to it are

List users: https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/team/members/list_v2
Fetch team_member_id for these users
Create dropbox client using

         const dbx: any = new Dropbox({
                           accessToken: access_token,
                           fetch: fetch,
                           selectUser: team_member_id
                       });


Recursively call below to get all files and folders for that particular team member. Please note the access token is obtained using oauth flow using admin account

        if (cursor === "") {
            result = await retry(() => dbx.filesListFolder({ path: "", recursive: true }));
        } else {
            result = await retry(() => dbx.filesListFolderContinue({ cursor }));
        }

Now I need to list all the team folders and its content too along with user specific content
For it I tried

Getting list of team folders using : const teamFolderUrl = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/team/team_folder/list';
Get the team_folder_id
Create dropbox client using

         const dbx: any = new Dropbox({
                           accessToken: access_token,
                           fetch: fetch,
                       });


Recursively call below to get all files and folders for that particular team member. Please note the access token is obtained using oauth flow using admin account

        if (cursor === "") {
            result = await retry(() => dbx.filesListFolder({ path: "/team_folder", recursive: true }));
        } else {
            result = await retry(() => dbx.filesListFolderContinue({ cursor }));
        }

but I am getting error
  error: `Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": This API function operates on a single Dropbox account, but the OAuth 2 access token you provided is for an entire Dropbox Business team.  Since your API app key has team member file access permissions, you can operate on a team member's Dropbox by providing the "Dropbox-API-Select-User" HTTP header or "select_user" URL parameter to specify the exact user <https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams>.`


require your help in detailed understanding of the issue

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Discuss-Dropbox-Developer-API/Listing-team-folders-and-content/td-p/794424 ]
